# pybliometrics not recognizing Scopus API

Tags: python, api, scopus, pybliometrics

I am trying to scrape data from Scopus using pybliometrics.

I got the API key from Scopus, but I didn't fill in the web address, which made the key **invalid/unauthorized**.

When I used it on my code, I got this error message:

```
Scopus401Error: The requestor is not authorized to access the requested view or fields of the resource
```

My question is, now I have got the **VALID KEY**, how can I reinsert it? I want to get the input box, but even when I restart the kernal (of jupyter notebook) nothing seems to change.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need a website to validate the key. But it can't hurt to have multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* a need for an insttoken to get this working, due to off main network access due to the pandemic, if that case you should contact integrationsupport@elsevier.com to arrange one.

Answer (score 0):

To change the key (or add new ones), you need to edit the file `config.ini` yourself. See https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html. The file is in folder `.scopus` in your home directory.